# Why does the button lift slightly when the inner content is inverted?

Tags: html, button, tailwind-css

When testing dropdown buttons and inversing their contents (Text & chevron icon) the one with the chevron in the left gets slightly lift.
[image: Button lifted]

Here's the code:

```html
<div class="mt-3">
    <button class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center" type="button">
        Dropdown button
        <svg class="ml-2 w-4 h-4" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"></path>
        </svg>
    </button>
    <button class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center" type="button">
        <svg class="mr-2 w-4 h-4" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"></path>
        </svg>
        Dropdown button
    </button>
</div>
```

If a put text to the left of the chevron the button gets leveled for some reason.
[image]

```html
a
<svg ...></svg>
Dropdown button
```

On the other hand, if a put an empty `<span>` the button gets pushed down
[image]

```html
<span></span>
<svg ...></svg>
Dropdown button
```

So I don't really know what is happening.

I already place the dropdown menu and wrap everything in a div, the dropdown menu works well and everything, but the buttons are still off, any thoughts?

Comment: The SVG is block tag like DIV and it is not inline with the text like SPAN.  To fixed the issue add flex style on the parent DIV.     <div class="mt-3" style="display:flex">

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `flex` and `item-center` for vertical alignment of both the dropdown buttons

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="mt-3 flex flex-row items-center space-x-4">
    <button class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center" type="button">
        Dropdown button
        <svg class="ml-2 w-4 h-4" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"></path>
        </svg>
    </button>
    <button class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center" type="button">
        <svg class="mr-2 w-4 h-4" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"></path>
        </svg>
        Dropdown button
    </button>
</div>
```